# Trying to resolve rwd grid viewport error

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid

I've been trying to experiment with a grid layout, after following w3schools guide on how to make a grid layout. No matter what I do, all the rows display 100% across the viewport. I've made a number of rows and divided them up with different column combinations and nothing will work.

A [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/aaronstran/pen/MWwYpVd) of the code.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6, sec1">Content</div>
    <div class="col-6, sec2">Content</div>
</div>
```

```css
[class*="col-"] {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768;){
    /*Desktops*/
    .col-1{width:8.33%;}
    .col-2{width:16.66%;}
    .col-3{width:25%;}
    .col-4{width:33.33;}
    .col-5{width:41.66;}
    .col-6{width:50%;}
    .col-7{width:58.33%;}
    .col-8{width:66.66%;}
    .col-9{width:75%;}
    .col-10{width:83.33%;}
    .col-11{width:91.66%;}
    .col-12{width:100%;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you need to understand the basics of html and css, css classes, inside a html tag are separated by space **NOT** by comma, knowing that, let's go to code.

1. You are using commas to separate classes, as mentioned

```html
<div class="col-6 sec1">Use classes like this!</div>
<div class="col-6, sec1">Do NOT use classes like this!</div>
```

2. Inside your selector you are forgotten to set a minimal height, otherwise, there's risk of some of your columns depending of declaration not appear.

```css
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

3. When declaring media queries you must threat it like any other unit. You forgot the unit in `min-width: 768`.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
    // Do your media
}
```

4. The clearfix hack you are using in your `.row` class, do not forget to add the rest of rules for before and it's own class. There is this [micro clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) you can take a look at.

```css
.row {
    *zoom: 1;
}

.row::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.row::before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
```

**HINT:**
If you take a look at some css frameworks tha majority of them has different column names for breakpoints like `col-lg-` for large devices `col-md-` for medium devices. It turn better if you adopt this practice when creating some column layout.

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grtavares/ohsauf48/) where I made some responsive columns.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I just need to look a little closer and search for small errors it seems like. During my first attempt, i did try to make classes for different screen sizes; however i thought that it was over complicating things at my current level. Definitely going to experiment with that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I noted two errors in your code:

1. Class names are `<div class="col-6,sec1">` **but it should be** `<div class="col-6 sec1">`
2. Media query is defines as `@media only screen and (min-width:768;)` **but it should be** `@media only screen and (min-width:768px)`